# how to translate array typedef with SWIG to Python?

Tags: python, swig

In C, I can write

foobar.h:

```
typedef int ARR[2];
```

foobar.c:

```
#include "foobar.h"
ARR arr;
```

and now I have an array `arr` of the proper size.  I can obtain that array without having to know the size, I just know the name of the type `ARR`. In other words, the header file hides the implementation details of `ARR` - the principle of encapsulation.

Now I want to translate this with SWIG to Python.  I have an interface

foobar.i:

```
%{
#include "foobar.h"
%}

%include "foobar.h"
```

and that means to me, just as above, that I should be able to use the interface coming out of `foobar.h` without having to know the details.  That is, I want to use the word `ARR` somehow on Python command line, to get an array of the correct size (perhaps initialized, in Python everything is initialized).

I am not trying to repeat C syntax in Python.  I want to repeat the principle of encapsulation.

What do I need to add to the interface to accomplish that?

I am trying and trying and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate via a struct or class: you'll likely want to expose, sooner or later, the array size to help with testing on the python side, and add operations like initialize values to 0, reset(0), adding two ARR arrays, and such. Then SWIG will do everything for you.

Comment: Agree.  It's not encapsulated if can't manipulate it without knowing its size.  Put it in a class.